# Site does not display translations

Tags: localization

I installed clean wordpress multisite. Bought a theme, installed woocommerce. Activated stuff, translated some and voila - everything is working. Translations and all.

i then uplodaded all the same stuff to my isp. Did all the same things i did at my own computer - but translations are not displayed there.

So i started googling things and Some of the posts mentioned that perhaps gettext is not working in the server. So i asked my isp and they said that they can confirm that php gettext is installed and working properly.

So how can i test this though? What could be other problems that translations are not working?

Alan